# okhttp android not returning proper response body

Tags: android, android-studio, okhttp

Below is the okhttp part my code

```
                    StringBuilder finalQuery = new StringBuilder(fq);
                    finalQuery.deleteCharAt(finalQuery.length()-1);
                    //System.out.println("Final search query : "+finalQuery.toString());

                    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(finalQuery.toString()).build();
                    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                            System.out.println("FAILED!!!");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                            if(response.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                StringBuilder strResponse = new StringBuilder(response.body().toString());
                                System.out.println("strResponse: "+strResponse.toString());
                                resp=strResponse.toString();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, onResponse.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.out.println("NOT SUCCESSFUL");
                            }

                        }
                    });
```

None of the strings are empty. The call to the website was successful, but the response is body is like this :

```
2020-05-05 13:47:40.982 15129-15161/com.example.lyricsapp I/System.out: strResponse: okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@b650836
```

When I used an online client to check for response using the same string, it was fine there. In my code, it isn't. What seems to be the error in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `string()` to retrieve the response body content as a string. That is, replace

```
response.body().toString()
```

with

```
response.body().string()
```

`toString()` is the method from `Object` and it just gives you the class name and  hash code.